# How to use JS to trigger ng-untouched/ng-empty? ( to ng-touched/ng-not-empty)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I usually use document.getElementById to fill in the form. However, I dont know how to fill in the form with angular. This is the Example:

```
<div class="control-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-6 form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-disabled="error" ng-attr-placeholder="{{placeholderFormodelanswer()}}" name="model_answer" ng-model="conditions.customs_modelanswer" placeholder="Please fill in the blank">
```

----------------------After I click and fill in the form, the class is changed--------------------

```
class="form-6 form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"
```

Is there any Javascript (like document.getElementById) can trigger ng-untouched and ng-empty instead of using mouse to trigger ng-untouched to fill in this form? How to use JS to fill in the form and pass the angular checking(ng pristine,ng valid,ng touched,ng dirty)?

Thank you